# Clip raster into numpy arrays based on shapefile or polygons

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I have a big raster file that I want to clip to 6 numpy arrays based on the polygons or shapefile. I have the shapefile and also the polygons as geopandas dataframe.  Can anyone please help me how to do it using python (no arcpy)

Comment: did you see the [py-gdal cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#clip-a-geotiff-with-shapefile)?

Comment: yes. i have 6 different polygons in my shapefile and i want to split my raster to 6 different numpy array each array corresponding to a polygon in the shapefile. How do I go it?

Comment: Assuming your polygons are independent features, you could [iterate over features](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#iterate-over-features) and then clip the file using each feature in turn.

Comment: thanks. the polygons are independent features. what i dont know is how to iterate over features to clip the the big raster file. Would you be able to elaborate more on how to clip please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a little generator which should do what you need. I've opted for the generator instead of iterating over the features directly, because it's more convenient if you'd like to inspect the arrays. If you want, you can still iterate over the generator.

```
import gdal
import ogr, osr

# converts coordinates to index

def bbox2ix(bbox,gt):
    xo = int(round((bbox[0] - gt[0])/gt[1]))
    yo = int(round((gt[3] - bbox[3])/gt[1]))
    xd = int(round((bbox[1] - bbox[0])/gt[1]))
    yd = int(round((bbox[3] - bbox[2])/gt[1]))
    return(xo,yo,xd,yd)

def rasclip(ras,shp):
    ds = gdal.Open(ras)
    gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()

    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    dataSource = driver.Open(shp, 0)
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer()

    for feature in layer:

        xo,yo,xd,yd = bbox2ix(feature.GetGeometryRef().GetEnvelope(),gt)
        arr = ds.ReadAsArray(xo,yo,xd,yd)
        yield arr

    layer.ResetReading()
    ds = None
    dataSource = None
```

Assuming your shapefile is called `shapefile.shp` and your raster `big_raster.tif` you can use it like so:

```
gen = rasclip('big_raster.tif','shapefile.shp')
```

---

```
# manually with next

clip = next(gen)

## some processing or inspection here

# clip with next feature

clip = next(gen)
```

---

```
# or with iteration

for clip in gen:

    ## apply stuff to clip
    pass # remove
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Kindly consider accepting the solution if it answered your question.

Comment: I did. Thanks once again. One last thing. Is it possible to exclude the no data pixels while creating the individual arrays?

Comment: How exclude? The line `arr = ds.ReadAsArray(xo,yo,xd,yd)` will read the array for the intersection between feature and raster. You can add any modification to `arr` before the `yield`

Comment: how to I get the coordinates of all pixel values in the image. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260304/extract-raster-values-within-shapefile-with-pygeoprocessing-or-gdal I am using the link as reference

Comment: This is supposing a shapefile of rectangular polygons, what if they are irregular?